# How to use my signed-certificate to generate pre-signed URL to object at Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, certificate, self-signed

I'd like to generate secure pre-signed url for the objects stored in Amazon S3. After I call `generatePresignedUrl` function in the Java SDK by passing resource key and bucket name, it returns an URL whose format is like `https://{bucketname}.amazonaws.com{key}?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ2ZNsY7UUIH7XMQA&Expires=1510834637&Signature=mkRSZBMdf4kAqCQr%2FMLQ2BMMI86Q%3D`

The returned URL is being accessed by `XMLHttpRequest` via JavaScript code. I'm doing simple GET request to my URL and I get the error `ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` in the web browser. The reason is that certificate used in data transfer is a user-signed certificate, that means not validated by certificate authority, so that's why browser refuses to get the resource. I'd like to use my signed certificate in resource access at Amazon S3 to prevent this error to come out. How can I instruct Amazon S3 to use my certificate rather than continue to use Amazon's unsecure user-signed certificate?

Greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error. It's because my bucket name contains dots, and because of that the browser recognized it as a different domain and did not validate the security certificate issued by Amazon.

Comment: That's correct.  To use https with S3, you need a bucket name without dots.  To use your own cert instead, you have to use Cloudfront to front-end S3, or you can deploy a reverse proxy in EC2 or reverse-proxy the requests through your web server to S3, which is not as inefficient as it may initially seem.

Answer (score 1):

Following from Yves' answer, you can generate presigned URLs that work with SSL using the JAVA SDK by specifying an empty bucket and concatenating the bucket with the object key.

So if you had the following call before:

```java
s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(<bucket>, <key>, <expiration>)
```

You can get a valid and SSL friendly url by instead calling:

```java
s3Client.generatePresignedUrl("", <bucket> + "/" + <key>, <expiration>)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Explicitly specify the region during presign

When you get an URL pre-signature, you can use many different URLs (not mentioning HTTP and HTTPS variations of the URL).

Note that I'm deliberately choosing a bucket name with a dot: `bucket.name`

If you go `aws s3 presign s3://bucket.name/object` you get

https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket.name/object?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxx&Signature=xxxxx&Expires=1543942893

Which redirects you to

https://bucket.name.s3.amazonaws.com/object?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxx&Signature=xxxxx&Expires=1543942893

As mentioned, the dot in the bucket name will make the default certificate invalid.

But when you explicitly **specify the region** like that `aws s3 presign --region=eu-west-1 s3://bucket.name/object` you get:

https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket.name/object?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxx&Signature=xxxxx&Expires=1543943326

Which is working nicely without needing you to remove the dot in your bucket name.